# Show app icon in the middle of the appbar

Tags: android, android-layout

Right now, as an example, the app looks like this:
[image]

How do I programatically or using xml make the appbar look like this:
[image]

I've tried setting the appbar icon as if it were a background, but it looks rather odd.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the application icon as a menu item to appbar with `android:show="always"`.

Another workaround is to **place an imageView in your toolbar**, which is inside the appBar. You can then change the position of this imageview through xml code or programmatically.

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ToolbarColoredBackArrow"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

        <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/indicator"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_small"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```